# How to ProxyPass websocket requests to node app via apache config?

Tags: node.js, apache, websocket, socket.io, feathersjs

I have a node app built with FeathersJS running on my server, I'd like it to be behind apache, I'm trying to use the mod_proxy module in apache to accomplish this but I've run into issues.

This is what my apache mod_proxy section looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyRequests off

    ProxyPass /ws/api/phone/ ws://localhost:3030
    ProxyPassReverse /ws/api/phone/ ws://localhost:3030

    ProxyPass /api/phone/ http://localhost:3030/
    ProxyPassReverse /api/phone/ http://localhost:3030/ 
</IfModule>
```

I've set my client socket configuration to the following:

```
var socket = io('/', { path: '/ws/api/phone/socket.io/', transports: ['websocket']});
```

When I try to open use the app, I get the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://local.mysite.com/ws/api/phone/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

I enabled apache logging, and this is what that error looks like:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2016:14:48:32 -0400] "GET /ws/api/phone/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 500 540 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"
```

If I run everything via localhost, it works perfect, no issues, so this is obviously an issue with ProxyPass. Any help would be greatly appreciated, or if there's another way I could accomplish putting the node app behind apache without using ProxyPass I'd be interested to hear any other solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me on 2.4.10:
It's been a while since I've configured this, but I know that I couldnt make it work using pure ProxyPass

```
ServerName api.example.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)    ws://localhost:3030/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPass / http://localhost:3030/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3030/
```

Comment: Do you remember anything about getting the error: `WebSocket connection to URL failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line`?

Comment: It's been like a year and time was short. I'm not sure what the actual error was. It "just would'nt connect". Have you tried the above?